# Where To Put .CSS Files For Adobe AIR HTML Control?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

If I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="caption">
        Test
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have this HTML as a STRING Called HtmlText, and I set the .htmlText property of an Adobe Air HTML Control to it something like this:

```
HTMLControl.htmlText=HtmlText;
```

Into what folder do I put 'base.css' so that it is applied to the content of the Adobe AIR HTML control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can use external CSS in this context.

But there is another way: you could load/inject the CSS file using JavaScript:

```
var css_file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets/thecss.css");
var css_string:String;
if(css_file.exists)
{
    var file_stream1:FileStream = new FileStream();
    file_stream1.open(css_file, FileMode.READ);
    css_string = file_stream1.readUTFBytes(file_stream1.bytesAvailable);
}
var css_style:Object = html.htmlLoader.window.document.createElement("STYLE");
css_style.type = "text/css";
css_style.innerText = css_string;
html.htmlLoader.window.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css_style);
```

Adaptation [of this](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Injecting_the_jQuery_library_into_a_page_loaded_in-19278.html).